# Nginx Docker On ElasticBeanstalk: No Such File Or Directory

Tags: java, nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an nginx docker. Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY server.8079.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

CMD nginx
```

Everything runs fine when I run this via the `docker run` command; both `/var/lib/nginx` and `/var/log/nginx` exist with the correct permissions, log files are created in `/var/log/nginx`, and `/var/lib/nginx/logs` is a symlink that points to `/var/log/nginx`. However, I cannot deploy this to my elastic beanstalk application. It fails due to the following error:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/lib/nginx/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2016/10/20 17:19:26 [emerg] 5#0: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Strangely, everything runs fine when I ssh into the Elastic Beanstalk server and start the docker with `docker run`. Here's the docker run file:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8079,
          "hostPort": 8079
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "containerPath": "/var/log",
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-NginxSSLRedirect"
        }
      ],
      "memory": 128,
      "essential": true,
      "image": "id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nginx-redirect-ssl",
      "name": "nginxSSLRedirect"
    }
  ],
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "2"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/Wonderfall/dockerfiles/issues/37 do you use aufs?

Comment: @user2915097 no, elastic beanstalk uses devicemapper.

Comment: additionally, I can start the container just fine using `docker run` by sshing into the elastic beanstalk server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the log folder was bound incorrectly. It should have been as follows:

```
"mountPoints": [
  {
    "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx",
    "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-NginxSSLRedirect"
  }
]
```